# Matching the gold on the Twining's Tea tin

Tags: packaging

I'm attempting to have a tin made that has a gold detail. The client likes the gold on the tiwinings tin. I don't know too much about printing on tin and so far the printer has been stumped attempting to create a color/effect similar to the Twining's Tea tin gold. Obviously a digital photo is incapable of totally depicting what I'm looking for but I think this one at least shows the sparkle of the thing. And it's a pretty common product so maybe someone out there even has one in their possession. Any thoughts on how to get a similar look would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: That's just sparkle paint. You need a printer or box/can manufacturer that uses sparkle paint. The effect is not achieved through file colors.

Comment: @Webster Repeated warning: please do not post answers in the comments. This is an upvoteable answer.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't so much a color as it's a metallic coating/paint.

You could try and find a manufacturer near you that has a catalog you could go through to try and find a suitable match for.

Comment: It can also be referred to as "metal flake" enamel. Visit any car body-shops that do painting for their opinions and expertise.